# To trim the domain from email and make value max 10 digits if it is more than 10 and ignore '.' if came in between . How can we do this?

Tags: java, substring, replaceall

To strip domain and allow max digit to 10 I am using this condition :

```
if (sender.indexOf('@') != -1 ) {
     sender = sender.substring(0, Math.min(sender.indexOf("@"), 10));
}
```

input   output
stackoverflow@gmail.com -> stackoverf

Now I need to add one more condition , If any '.' is present in between , ignore that '.'. For example -
stack.overflow@gmail.com -> stackoverf

For this I am trying this way :

```
if (sender.indexOf('@') != -1 ) {
  if(sender.contains(".") {
     sender.replaceAll("\\.","");
     sender = sender.substring(0, Math.min(sender.indexOf("@"), 10));
  }
}
```

Whether this approach is okay or some better approach we can implement.
Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I'd say you can get rid of that `if(sender.contains(".")`. It's not like `replaceAll` will take more time if you call it without checking first (I'd argue adding one method call will make it slower, if anything)

Comment: On `sender.replaceAll("\\.","");` you need to reassign the result to `sender` for it to work. Or you do it in one go: `sender = sender.replaceAll("\\.","").substring(0, Math.min(sender.indexOf("@"), 10));`

Comment: Good solution, though `sender = sender.replace(".","");`  and you are relying on `@` being present. You could do `sender = sender.replaceFirst("@.*$", "").replace(".", "").replaceFirst("^(.{10}).*$", "$1");`

Comment: Thank you so much , suggested solution is working :)